# Recognize $_REQUEST

Tags: php

```
$a = $_REQUEST['label'];
```

Now how can i recognize whether the value stored in variable `$a` was from `$_GET` or from `$_POST`? I wanted to redirect user if it was collected from `$_GET`. Is there any way to check ? PHP is little tough. Just something like this:

```
$var = recognize($_REQUEST['label']);
if($var == 'GET') { } else { }
```

Comment: Use `$_GET` and `$_POST`?

Comment: Under what circumstances is label arbitrarily sent from *either* `$_GET` or `$_POST`?

Comment: Sounds like your code is not well structured.

Comment: use like this `if($_GET['label']) { echo 'from get'; } else { echo 'from post'; }`. Hope it helps.

Comment: The point of `$_REQUEST` is that it combines a bunch of incoming data as one variable, for "convenience". You should not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a variable has been assigned, you won't be able to tell where it came from (usually).

Consider doing something like this, because if you use `$_REQUEST` it could even come from `$_COOKIE`!

```
if (isset($_GET['label'])) {
  // do redirect
} elseif (isset($_POST['label'])) {
  // do something else
}
```

Or, if you're passing that variable deep down where you can't tell where it originally came from:

```
class RequestParameter
{
    private $name;
    private $value;
    private $source;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
            $this->value = $_POST[$name];
            $this->source = INPUT_POST;
        } elseif (isset($_GET[$name])) {
            $this->value = $_GET[$name];
            $this->source = INPUT_GET;
        }
    }

    public function isFromGet()
    {
        return $this->source === INPUT_GET;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$a = new RequestParameter('label');

if ($a->isFromGet()) {
    // do redircet
}
```

But I would suggest structuring your code in a way that this is not necessary. One way is to check whether a POST was made:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `if($_GET['label']) { then redirect using header location; }`

Comment: OP wants to know whether you can tell from `$a` alone.

Comment: @Jack so how come your answer will tell if from '$a'

Comment: Because my answer includes a fanciful way of doing that :)

Comment: @Jack i did not seen it...+1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Better use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}
```

more details see documentation [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: This may not work as expected; A request can be a `POST` request, but still have values on the querystring, which `$_['GET']` can still access.

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['label'])){
//redirect
}
```